# Batch loop through all content of a specific directory and move those sub-directories and/or files except some files and folders, to other location

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, script

I have a source directory at path `D:\somepath` which contains mixed content i.e. files and folders both.

Now I want to move all folders and files except few files and folders from that source path to another target path say `D:\otherpath`.

But I cannot figure out how to loop through all the mixed content in the source directory with one `for` loop.

Below is the code I tried, it prints only folders and not files, but I want files too:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b "D:\somepath\"') DO ECHO %%f
PAUSE > NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

IF a PowerShell solution is ok and you have PowerShell 3.0+ then you could use this:

```
$except = @(
    "Thisfile.png",
    "ThisFolder",
    "ThisOtherFile.exe"
)

$source = "D:\somepath"
$destination = "D:\otherpath"

gci $source | % {
    if (!( $_.Name -in $except)) { 
        Move-Item $_.FullName $destination -Force 
        if ($?) { Write-Host "$($_.Name) was moved." }
    }
    else {  
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) was not moved." -fore Red
    }
}
```

just add the FileNames you don't want to process inside `$except = @()`